# How to write a :not() CSS exclusion working in every cases?

Tags: html, css, sass, less

I am trying to exclude some CSS rules when there is a defined CSS class as a parent with this rule:

```
.cc div:not(.cc-ei) li { color: red; }
```

But it doesn't work for all cases, as you can see in the code below, and the linked [Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/teeweetep/pen/abMagyG):

```css
.item {
  color: green;
}

.cc div:not(.cc-ei) li {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="cc">
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li>Should be red</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="cc-ei">
    <ul>
      <li class="item">Should be green</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="toto">
    <div class="cc-ei">
      <ul>
        <li class="item">Should be green</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How could I define the rule `.cc li { color: red; }` to exclude `<li>` that are in `<div class="cc-ei">`?

Comment: Please edit your question to use a [StackSnippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) instead of a CodePen so that all of the necessary code is contained within the question itself. Links go dead over time, and the goal of Stack Overflow is to have questions and answers be an evergreen resource for others looking for answers.

Comment: Apparently this is your first question, so I've taken the liberty of editing your question to include the relevant code and format is a running [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992); in future, please take the time to read *why* we require "*[mcve]*," and we *do* require it.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to achieve your requirements is to simply use the following rule, to style the `<li>` elements:

```
li:not(.cc-ei li) {
  color: red;
}
```

The revised code is below, with explanatory comments:

```css
body {
  font: 700 16px/1.5 Arial;
}

.item {
  color: green;
}

/*
  we select all <li> elements that do not match the selector
  passed to the :not() pseudo-class. This eliminates all
  <li> elements that are descendants of an ancestor element
  with the class of "cc-ei":
*/
li:not(.cc-ei li) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="cc">
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li>Should be red</li>
      <li>Should be red</li>
      <li>Should be red</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="cc-ei">
    <ul>
      <li class="item">Should be green</li>
      <li class="item">Should be green</li>
      <li class="item">Should be green</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="toto">
    <div class="cc-ei">
      <ul>
        <li class="item">Should be green</li>
        <li class="item">Should be green</li>
        <li class="item">Should be green</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

References:

- [`color`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color).
- [`font`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font).
- [`:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not).

Comment: The advantage here is that it's less fragile (less dependent on specific markup) than my solution.

Answer (score 1):

Logically your selector looks for list items in any div without the class. Since your list is nested in multiple divs, one without the class, that condition supersedes. You can specify a child relationship (as opposed to a general descendant relationship) to get it to work.

```css
.item {
  color: green;
}

.cc div:not(.cc-ei)>ul li {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="cc">
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li>Should be red</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="cc-ei">
    <ul>
      <li class="item">Should be green</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="toto">
    <div class="cc-ei">
      <ul>
        <li class="item">Should be green</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple as the author (me). Just tell it what you want: `li` items within `.cc-ei` should be green.

```css
.item {
  color: green;
}

.cc li {
  color: red;
}

.cc-ei li {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="cc">
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li>Should be red</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="cc-ei">
    <ul>
      <li class="item">Should be green</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="toto">
    <div class="cc-ei">
      <ul>
        <li class="item">Should be green</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```